# how to clear dns cache on vpn connection?

Tags: dns, vpn, 21.04, openconnect

After connecting to my customer's VPN, I need to issue this command:

```
service nscd reload
```

Or wait for some time before I can access internal services.

How can I make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating this script: `/etc/network/if-up.d/aftervpn`

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [[ "$IFACE" =~ ^(vpn)[0-9] ]]; then
    service nscd reload
fi
```